# Grayscale conversion algorithm of OpenCV's imread()

Tags: opencv, grayscale

What grayscale conversion algorithm does OpenCV's

```
cv::imread("image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

use?

Comment: You can easily test it yourself by comparing it with the one that you first load it in color style and then convert it to grayscale.

Comment: Would there even be a reason for it to be any different from `CV_BGR2GRAY`?

Comment: @a-jays Probably not, but you never know…

Comment: Please, do post what you find.

Comment: It is a bit late but it is `=0.299R+0.587G+0.114B`.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV 3.0:

- `cv::IMREAD_COLOR`: the image is decompressed by `cv::JpegDecoder` as `JCS_RGB` (three channel image) and then the `icvCvt_RGB2BGR_8u_C3R()` function will swap the red and blue channels in order to get BGR format.
- `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`: the image is decompressed by `cv::JpegDecoder` as `JCS_GRAYSCALE` (one channel image), all details of color conversion and other preprocessing/postprocessing is handled by the [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/). Finally, the decompressed data are copied into the internal buffer of the given `cv::Mat`.

Ergo no `cv::cvtColor()` is called after reading the image as `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now we just need to figure out the conversion algorithm of libjpeg. =P